# Constructor call during serialization

Tags: java, serialization, encryption, aes, state

I have a `KeyChain` class in my code, which allows me to store to disk and retrieve an encrypted list of credentials.

During the `KeyChain`'s construction, i initialize AES ciphers.

To serialize the object, i first serialize the credentials list into a buffer, then encrypt that buffer and put it into the original `OutputObjectStream`.

To deserialize it, i tried reading the `ObjectInputStream` into a buffer, decrypting it and deserializing my credentials from it, but to do that, i need to have the ciphers constructed in the first place. I can't do that since deserialization doesn't calls my constructor. How do i turn around this?

KeyChain:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512000];

    int readBytes = is.read(buffer);

    byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[readBytes];
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, readBytes);

    // Here it crashes and burns because i can't decrypt yet, the ciphers haven't been setup
    byte[] decryptedBytes = decryptBytes(encryptedBytes);

    ByteInputStream stream = new ByteInputStream(decryptedBytes, readBytes);
    ObjectInputStream unsafeInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(stream);
    try {
        Keys = (List<Key>)unsafeInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // Fail miserably
    }
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException {
    ByteOutputStream streamBytes = new ByteOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream unsafeOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(streamBytes);

    unsafeOutputStream.writeObject(Keys);
    unsafeOutputStream.flush();

    byte[] decryptedBytes = streamBytes.getBytes();

    byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptBytes(decryptedBytes);

    os.write(encryptedBytes);
    os.flush();

    Arrays.fill(decryptedBytes, (byte)0);
    Arrays.fill(encryptedBytes, (byte)0);
}
```

**gotcha:** I can't just call `initCryptograhy(char[] password)` in readObject because i just don't have the password available there, i can't pass it as an argument, this is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java actually has a facility called [`SealedObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html) for encrypting a serialized instance.  Maybe this would work better for what you are trying to achieve.  I think the key difference between what you are doing and what SealedObject does is that it does the decrypting in a second phase, not in the initial deserialization.

Comment: Oh god i can't believe i've done all that just to find out it's already been done by someone else... Well then, could you elaborate on this "second phase"?

Comment: Still i don't see how could i use this SealedObject, since in my `readObject` i don't have the ciphers ready to read the SealedObject back. Hints?

Comment: @wingleader - you can't do it in your `readObject`, that's the point.  you do the second call to get the contents of the SealedObject _after_ `readObject` completes (i.e. it is a second phase after the initial deserialization is done).

Comment: I actually solved it in a rather ugly way, but thanks for the advice, I'll do it this way.